# Sequelize - findOrCreate on the "through" table, on belongsToMany association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

First of all, I'm rather new to Node.JS and even newer to Sequelize, and this has been bothering me for a while. I have the following Model entities:

Match.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Match = sequelize.define('Match', {
            matchId: {
                type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
                field: 'match_id'
            },
            server: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            (...)
            rankedBoo: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                field: 'ranked_boo'
            }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Match.belongsToMany(models.Summoner, {as: 'Participants', through: 'SummonerMatch'});
            }
        },
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true
    });

  return Match;
};
```

Summoner.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Summoner = sequelize.define('Summoner', {
        summonerId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'summoner_id'
        },
        server: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        summonerName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'summoner_name'
        },
        mainChampion: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'main_champion'
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Summoner.belongsToMany(models.Match, {as: 'SummonerMatches', through: 'SummonerMatch'});
                Summoner.hasOne(models.RankedStats);
                Summoner.hasMany(models.RankedHistory, { as: { singular: 'RankedHistory', plural: 'RankedHistory' }});
            }
        },
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true
    });


  return Summoner;
};
```

SummonerMatch.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var SummonerMatch = sequelize.define('SummonerMatch', {
        championId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'champion_id'
        },
        role: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        (...)
        sightWardsBought: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'sight_wards_bought'
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true
    });

  return SummonerMatch;
};
```

Now I'm trying to create a new match, and associate it with a summoner, and I'm doing the following:

```
summoner.createSummonerMatch(matchInfo, matchDetails).then(
    function () {
        callback();
        return null;
});
```

Where *matchInfo* contains the attributes of the "Match" entity, and *matchDetails* contains the attributes of the "SummonerMatch" entity.

This is fine and all, but it doesn't check if the match already exists, so I'm trying to use *findOrCreate* here.

```
models.Match.findOrCreate({
    include: [ {model: models.Summoner, as: 'Participants'}],
    where: { matchId: matchInfo.matchId, server: matchInfo.server },
    defaults: {
        matchMode: queueType,
        matchDate: new Date(matchCreation),
        matchDuration: matchDurationInSeconds,
        rankedBoo: rankedBoo
        }
    }).spread(function(match, created) {
        console.log(created)
});
```

This almost does the trick (creates a new row in the Match table, but not in SummonerMatch). How would I proceed to insert information into SummonerMatch as well? Tried a few things (adding attributes to defaults, switching it to an array, tweaking around with the include, but no success so far.

I'm prolly missing out on something, but I can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciated :)

[EDIT] In case someone comes here looking for answers on how to do it, this works, but I'm not sure if it is the best approach:

```
models.Match.findOrCreate({
    include: [ {model: models.Summoner, as: 'Participants'}],
    where: { matchId: matchInfo.matchId, server: matchInfo.server },
    defaults: {
        matchMode: queueType,
        matchDate: new Date(matchCreation),
        matchDuration: matchDurationInSeconds,
        rankedBoo: rankedBoo
        }
    }).spread(function(match, created) {
        match.addParticipant(summoner, matchDetails).then(
            function () {
                console.log('Done')
            }
        )
});
```

It is creating a match if it doesn't exist, and adding a participant afterwards. Isn't there a way to do it all at once?

Comment: This may have been addressed here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417771/findorcreate-on-association-table