# Sequelize - Use set, add, create methods in models with belongs To Many associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new working with sequelize, and I don't know yet, how implements the methods that sequelize create when associate models with BelongsToMany associations. For example:

I have two models Users and Properties, a user can have more than one property, for each reason I've create the middle model PropertiesByUser when I have userId, propertyId, status and others fields.

I'm creating the users and properties separately, but when I want add a property to a user is when the process is complicated for me, because I don't know How create or use the model PropertiesByUser for create, add, set, properties for user, or add users to properties, someone can help me please?

I've read in blogs, some ways to use this but, any solution works. :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with [Belongs to Many Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/).

There you can see which functions you'll have access to (just replace the word Association with the actual name of yours).

Also, if you wanna create a property and associate it to an already created user, you can do something like this:

```
user.createProperty(propertyInfo).then(function() {
   console.log('Done')
})
```

Note: 'user' is the instance of the user you created, not the name of the model!

Hope this sets you on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Diogo, I've read the sequelize documentation about associations, but I need an example how use it, in the site only shows how use the get method, but don't explain how use add or set method. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi. If the example isn't enough, and since you didn't provide the code for your models, try checking this: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707805/sequelize-findorcreate-on-the-through-table-on-belongstomany-association[/link] I provided a few examples on how to use add/create. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Diogo, I have a doubt about your examples, the part where you do the models.Match.findOrCreate({....]) was into the summoner.createSummonerMatch(matchinfo,matchDetails) or, how you do that?

Comment: @user3229859 summoner.createSummonerMatch was my first attempt, but it didn't do what I wanted (checking if it existed), so I replaced with the second example. That bit of code works by itself.