# findOrCreate on association table

Tags: sequelize.js

*a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707805/sequelize-findorcreate-on-the-through-table-on-belongstomany-association), without a meaningful answer.*

Let's assume I have two tables,  Users and Projects.
We want to have a n:m relationship between those two entities.

We create

```
Project.belongsToMany(User, {
  through: UserProjectAssociation,
});
```

Now, 
if I do

```
myProject.addUser(1) // where projectId is 1 and userId is 1
```

this works.
But if I try to do the exact same operation again, it fails (because projectId and userId needs to be, of course, unique.
What I would like to do is

```
model.UserProjectAssociation.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      UserId: userId,
      ProjectId: projectId,
    }
  }
```

but I cannot find any reference on the findOrCreate api, on how to call it on an association table.

What's the best way to do so? The expected result of the command would be the record (either just inserted or already existing).

A Similar question would be for deleting a record. (if the record (userId:1, projectId:1) exists delete it, if not, don't do anything.

**Answer**

as pointed out by @piotrbienias in the comments, the syntax is exactly the same. Be sure that the database supports the Isolation level required. (In this case is SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ).

Comment: There is an api reference on [`findOrCreate`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findorcreateoptions-promiseinstance-created)

Comment: sorry but this doesn't answer my question. The documentation doesn't explain how is this working related to an association table

Comment: it works exactly the same on association table

Comment: how do you call the model of an association table? if you look at the code I've provided when I', trying to do findOrCreate on the association table, that fails.

Comment: What do you mean by fails? What error you get or what is the result of this code?

Comment: You are completely, right. With the debug on, I actually noticed that the query is executed correctly but needed the DB to support SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ.